# How to write an input handling function without global variables?

Tags: c

I want to write a function that will filter the input of the user and then give the filtered string back to the function that had called it.

Is this possible without creating an global variable as in my example?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input[10]; //global variable is meh!
char* input_function() {
    
    scanf("%s", input);
    return input;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", input_function());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a character pointer in the `main()` function and then pass it as an argument to `input_function()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
char* input_function(char* input) {
    scanf("%s", input);
    return input;
}
    
int main(void)
{
    char input[10];  // Need to allocate space
    printf("%s", input_function(input));
}
```

Comment: Where does `input` point?

Comment: It's used to store the buffer? I like how my answer is what the OP asked and I'm still getting downvoted.

Comment: A pointer doesn't store a buffer, but it may point to a buffer. In your case it doesn't since you don't have any buffers.

Comment: You need to allocate the buffer space either by a fixed allocation (I've submitted an edit to your code) or using `malloc()`

Comment: Of course, and using `scanf()` is unsafe because it can lead to a buffer overflow, but that's the way you'd do it. I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: You now have a buffer, so the code is technically correct. It is still dangerous because of the use of `"%s"` with `scanf`, but OP did it that way, so im going to let that slide..

Comment: thanks! i #include <stdio.h>
 
char* input_function(char* input) {
    scanf("%s", input);
    return input;
}
    
int main(void)
{
    char input[10];
    printf("%s", input_function(input));
}

Comment: @Anic17 *Of course, and using `scanf()` is unsafe because it can lead to a buffer overflow...*  No more or less safe than the entire C language.  Given `char input[10];`, `scanf("%9s", input);` is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible without creating an global variable as in my example?

As the other answer shows, yes, of course it is possible.

However, be careful about applying a blanket `meh` to global variables, which have their place.

Also be mindful that C allows module-scope, meaning it is accessible within the module, but not externally.  These should not be dismissed.

So it is perfectly acceptable to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[10]; //module scope is OK
static char* input_function() {
    
    scanf("%s", input);
    return input;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", input_function());
}
```